# Upload a Base64 String with GraphQL mutation

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, graphql, base64, apollo

I have an image taken with a device camera that I convert into a base64 string like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ........
```

I am trying to do a GraphQL mutation but I get an error that Variable "$file" got invalid value".

here is minified code:

```
  variables = {
    file: base64,
  };
  const { mutate } = useMutation( UPLOAD_FILE, () => ({ variables }));
```

How should I upload the image here? is base64 the correct type? Do I need to process or extract the base64 before sending to server?

Please help me understand how to upload base64 using GraphQL mutation.

Comment: *a base64 string like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,...`* - that's a very common misunderstanding. What you have there is not a base64 string, but a [data-url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) which contains a base64 string (the last part afer the `,`).

Comment: What is the input type for `file` in your `UPLOAD_FILE` mutation?

Comment: input is the camera that produces a web url, then I convert this to blob and then convert it to base64. 
I realized I don't need to convert it to base64 and just convert the blob to file.
However I got a server side error about the file extension restriction and after resolving server side, file was uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and converted a blob into a file:

```
var file = new File([blob], "file_name", {
  lastModified: new Date(),
});
```

It's also necessary to check the backend for file extension restrictions.